# DisclosureButton Indicator or Any kind of Accessory Type doesn't seem to appear when set on a UiTableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, accessorytype

This is a weird thing I have been noticing lately. I am not able to see the accessory Type for my UITableView Cell even after setting the accessoryType with the following code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"LocationCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Move to a New Location";
}else{
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.locArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
return cell;
}
```

It doesn't matter what accessory type I set. It always displays just the text label in the cell but, no button.  Am I missing something? Note that this is not the first time I am using a UITableViewCell. I have never come across this problem earlier. Meanwhile I am testing this on iOS6  and have confirmed this behavior both on the iPad simulator as well as the device it self.

Comment: Can you please put your answer down in the official way rather than a comment? Then you can mark it as correct and people will know that this question has been solved

Comment: I would if I could :) I just joined this site so I am not given the luxury to accept my own answers. If only all these things had been so easy! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well! I have solved this. My Viewcontroller was initially a subClass of UIViewController instead of UITableViewController. I did this thinking I would be adding extra views to the main View which would have nothing to do with the TableView. I then changed it to UITableViewController and voila it all worked perfect. But then this is a trade off between the flexibility provided by UiViewController and UitableViewController as I now have to add those extra views either in to the headerview or the footerview of the TableView. Nonetheless I have to deal with it any way. I hope this would help some one.